# url of the current page without page name and query string

Tags: php, url

As mentioned in the question, I want to get the url of the page without the page name and query string.

For example my url is:
http://sub.domain.com/app/page.php?var=abc

what I want from this is:
http://sub.domain.com/app/
without the query string and page name.

I found this tutorials:
http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/get-current-page-url.html
it was helpful but not exactly what I want.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Do you really want the protocol and domain name components?

Comment: $url = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'));
$protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
$url = $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$url."/";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following trick:

```
$location = dirname(__FILE__);
```

If you need an absolute URL, add the following in front of it:

```
$protocol = 'http'.(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '');
$root = $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Comment: I used this code, which worked for me: $url = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'));
$protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
$url = $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$url."/";

Comment: @happyhardik: There is more than one way of solving it, but `dirname(__FILE__)` is a lot easier to read than `substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'))` in my eyes.

Answer (score 5):

The `dirname(__FILE__)` is not the same as happyhardik's goal.

```
substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'))
```

returns: `/wwwroot/activetest2`

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

returns: `/home/content/94/3671394/html/wwwroot/activetest2`

To get the full URL:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'))
```

returns: `www.domainname.com/wwwroot/activetest2`

Answer (score 1):

The server vars don't hold only the path without the page name.

So you need to strip the page name from PHP_SELF (everything after the last / should do the trick)

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTACCESS for this problem. so by using htaccess your URL can be changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly answer that you are looking for is

```
$protocol = 'http'.(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '');
$currURL = $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'));
```

=======================================
**Explanation**
For Example your current url is 
http://sub.domain.com/app/page.php?var=abc 
it will return 
http://sub.domain.com/app