# Echo current URL minus current page

Tags: php

Let's assume the current url for my page is

```
http://domain.com/info/0/sign.php
```

how would I echo just `http://domain.com/info/0`

thank you

Comment: `echo "http://domain.com/info/0"` ? ^^. Do you mean what shows up in the webbrowser in the title bar? That depends on your web server configuration but it's typical to just rename your file to "index.php".+

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$path_parts = pathinfo($url); 
echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
```

Comment: i was thinking like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428386/url-of-the-current-page-without-page-name-and-query-string

Comment: try echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'].'/'.$path_parts['dirname'], "\n";

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [dirname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function should work:

```
$URL = ... # contains url
echo dirname($URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find [this function](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php) helpful. You can modify it to suit your needs.